# What to do with this series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I am new to this site and I wanted to ask a question regarding an exercise in Calculus II. I have this exercise written below:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(2n^5+2n^2)}{(n^3-2n^5)}$$

So far I have tried many convergence tests from Divergence Test until the Ratio Test but so far the results on the Convergence have been inconclusive and I also have not been able to find the Limit of the series.

Also one more question: If I use Integral Test and Divergence Test, do i have to include ${(-1)^n}$ in the Test?

I would really appreciate any help.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you revisit the question? $i$ is the index of the sum, but doesn't appear in the sequence in the sum.

Comment: Since there is a $(-1)^n$ in the series, aren't you supposed to use the Alternating Series Test?

Comment: Edited. Thanks.

Comment: I thought about that but the Alternating Series need the general term to be greater than 0 for all terms and general term does not satisfy the condition @AwnonBhowmik

Comment: Still it does not make any sense, the series is divergent. Moreover $n$ is the summation index so it cannot appear in the result.

Comment: Edited again. My bad for the misunderstanding

Comment: Thank you. Please pay attention when posting questions. Now we talk about something that makes sense :)

Comment: Yeah. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Begin with checking whether the general term tends to $0$. This is a *sine qua non* condition.

Comment: The question does not make any sense as it is. It has to be revised and edited. It is not even clear which is the "general term".